# Store UITableViewCell information into core data without segue xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I have a TableViewController and I have a UITableViewCell which can be expanded. When it is expanded I would like to save the data which was set with a UIBarButtonItem, so this button would call a method for the saving. I tried to save it in my ViewController implementation file but I always get an error saying:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
```

I copied all the essential code to my AppDelegate implementation file from another project which is just a basic project using core data. I made my xcdatamodeld file as well, with one Alarm entity and seven attributes. I have also created an NSManagedObject class for the entity. In addition I have an AlarmCell in which I set the UITableViewCell properties.

My ViewController.m code is:

```
- (IBAction)optionSet:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
  if ([_alarmOperation.title isEqual:@"Save"])
  {
      [self saveTheAlarmFinally];
  }
}

BOOL monSet, tueSet, wedSet, thuSet, friSet, satSet, sunSet;

- (void) saveTheAlarmFinally
{
AlarmCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AlarmCell"];

if (cell.mon.tintColor == RGB(0, 204, 102))
{
    monSet = YES;
}
else
{
    monSet = NO;
}
if (cell.tue.tintColor == RGB(0, 204, 102))
{
    tueSet = YES;
}
else
{
    tueSet = NO;
}
if (cell.wed.tintColor == RGB(0, 204, 102))
{
    wedSet = YES;
}
else
{
    wedSet = NO;
}
if (cell.thu.tintColor == RGB(0, 204, 102))
{
    thuSet = YES;
}
else
{
    thuSet = NO;
}
if (cell.fri.tintColor == RGB(0, 204, 102))
{
    friSet = YES;
}
else
{
    friSet = NO;
}
if (cell.sat.tintColor == RGB(0, 204, 102))
{
    satSet = YES;
}
else
{
    satSet = NO;
}
if (cell.sun.tintColor == RGB(0, 204, 102))
{
    sunSet = YES;
}
else
{
    sunSet = NO;
}    

[self createNewAlarmWithMonday:monSet Tuesday:tueSet Wednesday:wedSet Thursday:thuSet Friday:friSet Saturday:satSet Sunday:sunSet];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Alarm"];

NSError *requestError = nil;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSArray *alarms = [[appDelegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&requestError];

}

- (BOOL) createNewAlarmWithMonday:(BOOL)paramMonday
                       Tuesday:(BOOL)paramTuesday
                       Wednesday:(BOOL)paramWednesday
                       Thursday:(BOOL)paramThursday
                       Friday:(BOOL)paramFriday
                       Saturday:(BOOL)paramSaturday
                       Sunday:(BOOL)paramSunday                   
{
BOOL result = NO;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


Alarm *newAlarm = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Alarm" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];

if (newAlarm == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to create the new alarm.");
    return NO;
}

newAlarm.monday = [NSNumber numberWithBool:paramMonday];
newAlarm.tuesday = [NSNumber numberWithBool:paramTuesday];
newAlarm.wednesday = [NSNumber numberWithBool:paramWednesday];
newAlarm.thursday = [NSNumber numberWithBool:paramThursday];
newAlarm.friday = [NSNumber numberWithBool:paramFriday];
newAlarm.saturday = [NSNumber numberWithBool:paramSaturday];
newAlarm.sunday = [NSNumber numberWithBool:paramSunday];

NSError *savingError = nil;

if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError])
{
    return YES;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to save the new alarm. Error = %@", savingError);
}

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conception is wrong. You shouldn’t call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: on save method - this should be called only when table view wants cell to display. Also, cells shouldn’t store any data, they should only inform your controller about change and controller should know what to do with cell action. Alternatively cell should have model (Alarm) associated with it and modify it directly. It’s also wrong to check cell states by comparing it’s colors (colors may change and your code will stop working).

Regarding your error with `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` I see that you are inserting object with `[appDelegate managedObjectContext]` and later saving it with `self.managedObjectContext` - maybe, the second one is improperly initialized - persistent store is not set?

Comment: So I should just save the data in the ViewController based on the UITableviewCells behaviour? And so I should implement the Alarm.h in the AlarmCell as well?

I'm sorry, I'm a beginner. I set up the appDelegate managedObjectContext in order to get the object context from the AppDelegate. Shall I do that, or I can define the managedObjectContext in the ViewController file as well? I haven't set any persistent store yet, I thought I could solve without that. Shall I set a persistent store in order to work.

Comment: I think, you should start programming with good book like this http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/ios-programming.html. Also, read Apple documentation - `NSManagedContextObject` can’t save data without persistent store. So, when creating new `NSManagedObjectContext` just set same persistent store from appDelegate. Also, read tutorials available on Apple site (Recipes.app is a good start) and on other sites like http://www.raywenderlich.com.